# json_decode returns null on a valid value php

Tags: php

Here is my code:

```
   echo '<br/>';
   echo 'Json data from DB   '.json_encode($output);
   $data=array();
   $array=json_decode($output,true);
   echo '<br/>';
   echo 'Concerted into an array   '.json_encode($array);
```

and here is the output:

```
Json data from DB  [{"0":"1","key-1":"1","1":"1","key-2":"1","2":"1","key-3":"1","3":"1","key-4":"1"}] 
Concerted into an array null
```

why json_devode returns null? If I try the same like this:

```
$data = '[{"0":"1","key-1":"1","1":"1","key-2":"1","2":"1","key-3":"1","3":"1","key-4":"1"}]';

// convert to an array
$data = json_decode($data, true);
```

then it is printed out normally:

```
Json data from DB  [{"0":"1","key-1":"1","1":"1","key-2":"1","2":"1","key-3":"1","3":"1","key-4":"1"}] 
Concerted into an array  {"0":"1","key-1":"1","1":"1","key-2":"1","2":"1","key-3":"1","4":"1","key-4":"1"}
```

Comment: Triple check what variable you're trying to decode!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `json_decode` takes a string and `$output` isn't a string (as evidenced by `json_encode`: it's an array).

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be mixing things up. In your example `$output` seems to be an array already and you want to decode it again? How?

When you do this:

```
json_encode($output);
```

It returns a proper JSON object, meaning that `$output` is already an array. And you can not `json_decode` a non-JSON object. It seems like you can just use `$output` directly, or you need to state your problem more clearly.